# Cannot open my QML MessageDialog using my C++ signal

Tags: c++, qml, tableview, sudoku

I have a sudoku grid, and I want to validate it so that a number cannot be entered in the same row and column. If this happens, I want the message dialog box to open.
I have the function `verif_complet` that checks the row and column. I emitted a signal, but it is not working correctly, and the message dialog is not opening.

What could be the problem and what can I do to make this work?

This is the QML code of the `TableView`:

```
TableView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true

    model: SudokuGrid {
        id: grid
    }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        required property var model
        implicitWidth: 50
        implicitHeight: 50

        TextField {
            id: textField
            anchors.fill: parent
            validator: IntValidator { bottom: 1; top: 9 }
            text: model.display !== undefined ? model.display.toString() : ""

            readOnly: model.display !== undefined && model.display !== 0

            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter

            background: Rectangle {
                color: model.row % 2 ? "lightpink" : "#bfa6ac" && textField.acceptableInput ? "#FFEFD5" : "#bfa6ac"
                border {
                    width: 1
                    color: "white"
                }

            }

            color: "black"

            onEditingFinished: {
                if (!model.verif_complet(model.row, model.column, parseInt(textField.text))) {
                    grid.invalidInput();
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 1
            height: parent.height
            color: model.column % 3 == 0 ? "black" : "transparent"
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 1
            color: model.row % 3 == 0 ? "black" : "transparent"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message dialog:

```
MessageDialog {
    id: msgDial
    text: "Invalid number."
    informativeText: "Do you want to save your changes?"
    buttons: MessageDialog.Ok

    onAccepted: msgDial.close()
}
```

This is the connection between the signal and QML to open the message dialog, but the message dialog is not opening.

```
Connections {
    target: grid
    function onInvalidInput() {
        msgDial.open()
    }
}
```

This is the C++ code of the `setData` function:

```cpp
bool Grid::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    if (role == Qt::EditRole) {
        if (!checkIndex(index))
            return false;

        int inputValue = value.toInt();

        if (inputValue < 1 || inputValue > 9)
            return false;

        SudokuGenerator sudokuGenerator(1);

        if (sudokuGenerator.verif_complet(index.row(), index.column(), inputValue)) {
            gridData[index.row()][index.column()] = inputValue;
            emit dataChanged(index, index);
            return true;
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Invalid number in the same row, column, or 3x3 square!";
            emit invalidInput();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and this is the `verif_complet` function:

```cpp
bool SudokuGenerator::verif_complet(int i, int j, int nr) {
    if (verif_col(j, nr) == true && verif_lin(i, nr) == true && verif_patrat(i - (i % 3), j - (j % 3), nr) == true)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I tried to call the `verif_complet` function and emit a signal.

Comment: You have to find out, at which part it stops workings as expected. Add a debug message in verfiy_complet to check if it is called. Try to return false in verify_complet. Call invalidInput in Component.onComplete to check, if the MessageBox is correct etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can build a solution using `RegularExpressionValidator` instead of `IntValidator`. The regular expression will begin by allowing the characters from "0123456789" but, over time, the list of available characters disappears as you enter new values.

Because we're ensuring the input is always valid, there is no need for a post-editing check and no need for a dialog.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    title: "Sudoku Test"
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: debugCheckBox.checked ? 9 * 60 : 9 * 40
        height: width
        Repeater {
            model: SudokuModel { id: sudokuModel}
            delegate: SudokuCell {
                debug: debugCheckBox.checked
                onActiveFocusChanged: if (activeFocus) updateValidChars()
                function updateValidChars() {
                    let ok = "0123456789".split("");
                    for (let idx = 0; idx < sudokuModel.count; idx++) {
                        let m = sudokuModel.get(idx);
                        if (m.i === i && m.j === j) continue;
                        if (m.i !== i && m.j !== j) continue;
                        if (m.v === 0) continue;
                        if (m.v < 1 || m.v > 9) continue;
                        ok[m.v] = "";
                    }
                    validChars = ok.join("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        CheckBox { id: debugCheckBox; text: "Debug" }
    }
}

// SudokuModel.qml
import QtQuick
ListModel {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                append( {i:i,j:j,v:0} );
    }
}

// SudokuCell.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
TextField {
    property bool debug: false
    property var validChars: "0123456789";
    property var regex: new RegExp('^[' + validChars + ']$');
    property int cellSize: debug ? 60 : 40
    background: Rectangle {
        border.color: "black"
        Text {
            visible: debug
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.margins: 2
            text: validChars; font.pointSize: 6
        }
    }
    x: j * cellSize
    y: i * cellSize
    width: cellSize
    height: cellSize
    color: acceptableInput ? "green" : "red"
    text: v
    validator: RegularExpressionValidator { regularExpression: regex }
    onEditingFinished: v = parseInt(text)
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)